# Incorrect credentials for pushing to git repository with netbeans8

Tags: git, netbeans

[image]

I've just upgraded to netbeans 8. I have a git repository on bitbucket.org  when I try to push to it with netbeans 7.4 it works fine. If I close Netbeans 7.4 , open NB8 and try to push to the same repository I get:

```
Incorrect credentials for repository at bitbucket.org:MYACCOUNT/MYPROJECT.git.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old but it comes up when I search every time so I'm going to put the fix here for next time.

To fix this edit your PROJECT/.git/config file where PROJECT is the path of your project.

Change the url line under the [remote "origin"] section:

```
url = https://YOURUSERNAME@bitbucket.org/YOURUSERNAME/REPO.git
```

Be sure to replace YOURUSERNAME with your bitbucket username and REPO with your bitbucket repository which should have already been there.